# How to apply correct filter to {{ current_tags }} to display tag names not tag slugs

Tags: filter, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I want to alter this code to display the text within the anchor in readable format. I wish to display the tags name or title but it is currently displaying the tags as slugs.

Here is the snippet:

```
<!-- Creates the link as a variable, which is in 'tag_slug+tag_slug' format --> 
{%- capture tag_url -%}{{ collection.url }}/{{ current_tags | join: "+"}}{%- endcapture -%}
<!-- HELP ME display the text inside the anchor in 'tag_title + tag_title' format. It currently displays the text of the anchor in 'tag_slug + tag_slug' format which is not very readable -->
<a class="breadcrumbs__link" href="{{ tag_url }}" aria-current="page">{{ current_tags | join: " + "}}</a>
```

I have tried a handful of things but have been unsuccessful. One of which was:

```
{{ current_tags.title | join: " + " }}
```

What is the equivalent to current_tags.title in liquid?

Here is an example output of the link:

```
<a class="breadcrumbs__link" href="/collections/example/tag-one+tag-two" aria-current="page">tag-one + tag-two</a>
```

This would be much easier to follow as a user if it was:

```
<a class="breadcrumbs__link" href="/collections/example/tag-one+tag-two" aria-current="page">Tag one + Tag two</a>
```

Where the tags would not have spaces removed, and the first letter will be capitalised. One thing to consider is that some tags require the dash to remain if it is already present in the tag title. So replacing dashes for spaces will not work. It will just create another issue.

*EDIT* - Another method that does not work:

```
{%- capture tag_url -%}{{ collection.url }}/{{ current_tags | join: "+"}}{%- endcapture -%}
<a class="breadcrumbs__link" href="{{ tag_url }}" aria-current="page">
    {% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
        {% if current_tags contains tag %}
            <div class="current-tag">{{ tag.title }}</div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</a>
```

*EDIT 2* - Another failed attempt:

```
{% for tag in current_tags %}
    <div class="current-tag">{{ tag.title }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi Jason. There is a general agreement that signatures should not be placed in posts. I've edited this out of a number of your posts already, could you refrain from adding any more?

Comment: @halfer - my bad, I’m Canadian...

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not by the book. I have not been able to find any documentation on how to iterate through the current_tags, display the tags by their readable name & add a join value such as ' + '.

However I have managed to loop through the current tags, then use CSS to change their appearance to better suit the style we wished for. So again this is not the textbook way of acheiving this and the results will not be 100% correct all the time but it is a substantial improvement on the previous display.

This will take the value of for example 'balances-scales-accessories+bench-scales' and convert it into 'Balances Scales Accessories + Bench Scales'. The 100% answer would look a little more like 'Balances, Scales & Accessories + Bench Scales'.

Where this solution fails is:
The ',' and '&' characters are removed.
The '-' are removed when in very niche situations these are actually a desired character like in the word 'Semi-gloss'.

Liquid:

```
<!-- Generate link as previously achieved -->
{%- capture tag_url -%}{{ collection.url }}/{{ current_tags | join: "+"}}{%- endcapture -%}
<!-- Add generated link to anchor tag -->
<a class="breadcrumbs__link" href="{{ tag_url }}" aria-current="page">
    <!-- Loop through tags present in current tags list -->
    {% for tag in current_tags %}
        <!-- Wrap echoed tag in a span so it is targetable, replace the dashes for spaces, and make the whole thing lowercase -->
        <span class="breadcrumb-tag">{{ tag | replace: '-', ' ' | downcase }}</span>
    {% endfor %}
</a>
```

CSS:

```
/* Capitalise first letter of each word of the breadcrumb */
.breadcrumbs__link .breadcrumb-tag {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
/* Add a before on each tag that is not the first, to display a '+' symbol indicating there are multiple tags selected */
.breadcrumbs__link .breadcrumb-tag + .breadcrumb-tag:before {
    content: ' + ';
}
```

Again not perfect but will do until someone can create a more reliable solution in liquid.